# Azure ARM get IP address of subnet

Tags: azure, templates

I'm creating a ARM template, but I'm having a troble with getting the first IP of a existing subnet.

Is there any way I can get the first IP of a existing subnet?

Here is a part of my template, I'm trying to get the first IP and put it into customData.

```
"osProfile": {
    "computerName": "[variables('vmname')]",
    "adminUsername": "[parameters('user')]",
    "adminpassword": "[parameters('password')]",
    "customData": "[base64(reference(variables('subnetId'), '2018-04-01').firstIP)]"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, you'd need to do some string manipulation. first get the addressPrefix:

```
reference(variables('subnetId'), '2018-04-01').addressPrefix
```

then split it by `/` and take the first part, then split it by `.` and reconstruct it by cast last octet to int and adding 4 (it is always 4, because first 3 addresses of each network are reserved by Azure) to it.

ps. there is no way to know what is the first actual TAKEN address from the subnet inside arm template

Comment: Should we worry about the weird subnet? for example 192.168.1.1/24 or 192.168.1.1/19

Comment: i dont understand the question, subnet(s) cant be weird.https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/164015/understanding-tcp-ip-addressing-and-subnetting-basics

Comment: Thank your for your answer, it's really helpful .